# Javascript function call in url

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I want to login a website with javascript and i dont know it is allowed. I use javascript code in url and it gives me Invalid left-hand side in assignment
    at :1:10   error.

```
javascript:document.getElementById("OtherUsername")="myid";document.getElementById("OtherPassword")="mypassword";$("#btnSend").click();
```

Comment: you need to use value attribute `document.getElementById("OtherUsername").value = "myuid"`, not sure what you are trying to do but you aremixing jquery n JS

Answer (score 1):

As Vinod stated, you are trying to assign `myid` (a string) to `document.getElementById("OtherUsername")`, an object. That won't work. You need to assign it to `document.getElementById("OtherUsername").value`

This should work:

```
javascript:document.getElementById("OtherUsername").value="myid";document.getElementById("OtherPassword").value="mypassword";$("#btnSend").click();
```

The last bit `$("#btnSend").click();` will only work if they have jQuery active on that site, or if you include it through use of a plugin somehow.

Answer (score 1):

you can not Assign a value to a dom element

if **OtherUsername** element and **OtherPassword** element is a form you can follow my code

```
document.getElementById("OtherUsername").value="myid";
document.getElementById("OtherPassword").value="mypassword";
$("#btnSend").submit(); //btnSend should be the from id
```

Comment: I was thinking i tried too but to be sure i tried again and it is happened , thanks

Comment: in the next time, ask javascript question with HTML code will be better